# Maven doesn't see dependency

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to add dependency to one module. here is the code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.messagedna.dlp</groupId>
       <artifactId>producer</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the part of the pom file of the module `producer`:

```
<parent>
      <artifactId>DLP</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.messagedna.dlp</groupId>
      <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.messagedna.dlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>producer</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>producer</name>
```

but when I'm trying to compile the first module I get the following:

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/messagedna/dlp/producer/1.0/producer-1.0.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.messagedna.dlp:producer:pom:1.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/messagedna/dlp/producer/1.0/producer-1.0.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.messagedna.dlp:producer:jar:1.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) com.messagedna.dlp:producer:jar:1.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.messagedna.dlp -DartifactId=producer -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.messagedna.dlp -DartifactId=producer -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) com.messagedna.dlp:DLPServer:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    2) com.messagedna.dlp:producer:jar:1.0

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  com.messagedna.dlp:DLPServer:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

how to make it build?

Comment: Are you sure that the artifact in repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you haven't set up a proper parent-child relationship between the producer project and the one that depends on it. Until you set that up, you'll need to manually run `mvn install` on the producer project before trying to build any of the projects that depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

To use a library in maven it must be

- in maven central
- in another repository you have access to.
- install locally.

If it is none of these, you need to follow the instructions maven gives you.